# Share the same source between layers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I want to change the style of my layer on a certain zoom (circle to symbol). When I cross zoom 5, what I thought I could do was to remove my previous layer, then create a new one with the old source. Actually, it gives me an error.

If I create a new source with the same data everything works fine, the error is about the source. What I don't understand is that the source is still present as I can interact with it.

Please find my [fiddle](http://codepen.io/poupi/pen/BLxkbB/), open the console to see :

- the zoom (wait for zoom 5)
- the data contained by the source
- the error

  ```
  glMap.addSource('yacht', {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: data,
      buffer: 256
  });
  glMap.addLayer({
      "id": "yachtL",
      "type": "circle",
      "interactive": true,
      //'style': '/bright-v8.json',
      "source": "yacht",
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
          'circle-color': '#262626',
          'circle-opacity': 0.8
      }
  }/*, "cargoL"*/);

      removeSpinner();
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the new layer a new id, then it will work. Currently they both have the id of 'yachtL'.

Comment: Well you're right... I don't understand why as I delete the previous layer with the same id 'yachtL'. Could you explain? 

The thing is I don't want to lose the interactions I have with my layer (i.e : my functions call yachtL, no matter what zoom it is, I don't want to duplicate my functions for each layer I have). 

In my app, for that issue, if I remove the source then re-create the same (with the same id) I can use yachtL as a layer id. I guess I'll keep that workaround instead of change the id of my layer

Comment: I'm new to mapbox gl, so not sure I truly understand all the functions. I have actually had a hard time figuring out how to change the style of a single feature in a layer, but anyway glad that helps.